# twitter4j get the tweeted id

Tags: android, twitter4j

am using twitter4j for my app. am able to post media/text using twitter4j. but i want the id of my status.

```
The method getId() is undefined for the type StatusUpdate
```

i have tired using

```
StatusUpdate status = new StatusUpdate(mfinalmsg);

            if (imgdata != null) {
                ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgdata);

                status.setMedia("pic", bis);

            }

            twitter.updateStatus(status);
             long statusId = (int)status.getId();
```

so i have replaced StatusUpdate with status. but how can i upload media/urllink.

```
 twitter4j.Status status = twitter.updateStatus(mfinalmsg);
             long statusId = (int)status.getId();
```

i am ready to use twitter rest api. but i dont know how to send params . please guide me ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
StatusUpdate statusUpdate = new StatusUpdate(mfinalmsg);

if (imgdata != null) {
    ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(imgdata);    
    statusUpdate.setMedia("pic", bis);   
}

Status status  = twitter.updateStatus(statusUpdate);
long statusId = (int)status.getId();
```

`twitter.updateStatus()` method returns Status object. Use that object to get id, not the object of StatusUpdate class.